# Understanding where to put config file in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor

If anyone could point me in the right direction then I would really appreciate it. I am sorry but this is a long post so I apologise.

In my old ASP.NET webforms app I had the following project structure:
BusinessLayer
DataAccessLayer
UtilitiesLayer
WebUI

WebUI would have project dependancies of
BusinessLayer
UtilitiesLayer

BusinessLayer would have project dependancies of
DataAccessLayer
UtilitiesLayer

WebUI would have a web.config file that contains the database settings etc..

Now in my new Blazor WASM app I have the following project structure:
APILayer
BusinessLayer
DataAccessLayer
UtilitiesLayer
Server.UI
Wasm.UI

APILayer would have project dependancies of
BusinessLayer and call the methods directly

Wasm.UI would have project dependancies of
UtilitiesLayer and will call APILayer for getting data

Server.UI would have project dependancies of
UtilitiesLayer and will call APILayer for getting data

BusinessLayer would have project dependancies of
DataAccessLayer
UtilitiesLayer

Now my question is where do I put the appsettings.json that contains the DB settings. At the moment I have a class in the UtilitiesLayer called WebsiteSettings like

```
public static string ThisDatabaseConnectionString { get; set; }
```

And in the MainLayout.razor set the setting when I first run the app

```
@inject IConfiguration configuration
UtilitiesLayer.WebsiteSettings.ThisDatabaseConnectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("ThisDatabaseConnectionString").Value;

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ThisDatabaseConnectionString": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=thisDB;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
  },
```

This all works ok if I put a project dependancy direct to the BusinessLayer but because I am calling the BusinessLayer through HttpClient in the APILayer like this:

```
sUrl = "https://localhost:7263/DBAPIs/GetAllUser";

using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
    oDic = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Users>>(sUrl);
}
```

And in the BusinessLayer

```
DataTable dt = MySQLHelper.ExecuteDataTable(UtilitiesLayer.WebsiteSettings.ThisDatabaseConnectionString, sqlCommand);
```

UtilitiesLayer.WebsiteSettings.ThisDatabaseConnectionString is always null.

So where can I put the settings file that I can always access the UtilitiesLayer.WebsiteSettings.ThisDatabaseConnectionString in all projects?

Comment: Side note, [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedsettings.json config file which can be shared accross projects.You can load shared settings in below method

```
  .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
  var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

   var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "..", "Shared");

config
    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: true) // When running using dotnet run
    .AddJsonFile("SharedSettings.json", optional: true) // When app is published
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
```

Please use below link for detailed implementation

https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will look into this and get back to you :) Appreciate your time answering my post